# Understanding Multi-headed Attention from architecture details

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, transformer, attention-mechanism

I've a conceptual question

BERT-base has a dimension of 768 for query, key and value and 12 heads (Hidden dimension=768, number of heads=12). The same is conveyed if we see the BERT-base architecture

```
(self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
)
```

Now, my question is:

> Can I consider the first 64 neurons from the *out_features* as the
> first-head, the next 64 neurons from the *out_features* as the 2nd
> head and so on? (sec 3.2.2 from original paper; [Link](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf))

P.S: I referred to some of the previous posts ([example](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/88330/how-do-the-linear-layers-in-the-attention-mechanism-work)), but I would appreciate any validation on this thought-process as it's similar but not same.

**Update**

Here's a code which prunes a particular % in particular layer depending on *layer_index* and *prune_percentage*

```
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

linear_layers_list = []
for name, layer in model.named_modules():
    if name in model_layers_list:
        linear_layers_list.append(layer)
print(f"No of linear layers are: {len(linear_layers_list)}")

layer = linear_layers_list[layer_index]
if prune_type == 'ln_structured':
    # Ln structured with n=1 i.e L1 pruning
    prune.ln_structured(layer, name='weight', amount=prune_percentage, dim=0, n=n)
```

Here, I can understand that I can basically pass the Linear module and prune x% of weights.

Now, I would like to prune/remove one head in a similar fashion. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

As shown in the original Transformer paper that you linked, the results of the individual heads are concatenated into a single vector but then they pass through another linear layer, which does not respect the individuality of the parts:

[image]

Therefore, the output of the model no longer contains separate parts per each head.

Comment: Thanks for the response Noe. Suppose I want to prune/remove a particular head (say 3rd head). From the above architecture, how can I achieve that! Because I'm having a tough time to understand the concept from the model.summary() point of view!

Comment: I guess it depends on the purpose of pruning. If you want to save the computation of some heads, I guess that, apart from removing those heads, you should trim the matrices of the final linear layer to remove the columns associated to the parts of the concatenated vector that belonged to those heads. If you don't care about saving computation, you can just zero-out the results of the computations of the heads you want to prune.

Comment: I've updated the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Example applications are below:

1. https://lena-voita.github.io/posts/acl19_heads.html
2. https://github.com/pmichel31415/are-16-heads-really-better-than-1